# Extraño comportamiento de html

Tags: html, css, django

Simplemente es una encuesta donde muestro las preguntas y opciones guardadas en una base de datos. Pero por alguna razon "Diciembre" sale en un lugar, donde DEFINITIVAMENTE no deberia estar.
Alguien tiene idea de lo que puede estar pasando? Asi es como luce la pagina:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de la parte de la encuesta:

```
<article style="color: cornsilk; background-color:  rgb(153, 152, 160); width: 70%; margin:0 auto; border-radius: 1%;">
{% if encuesta %}<!--Si hay algo en encuesta entonces-->
    <ul>
        <form  style="padding: 40px;" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

    {% for question in encuesta %}
        <p style="text-align:center;">{{question.pregunta}}</p>
      
        {% for choice in opcion %}
        <table style="margin: 0 auto; float: center; display: inline; color: cornsilk;"><tr>
        
            {% if question.id == choice.id_pregunta_id %}
            
            <td>{{choice.opciones}}
            <input type="checkbox" name="opciones">
            </td>
            </tr>
            {% endif %}
            
       
        </form>
    
        {% endfor%}
        
    
    {% endfor %}
    <br><hr>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar información" style="margin-left: 420px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    </ul>
{% else %}<!--Si no hay nada en encuesta-->
    <p>Sin encuestas disponibles</p>
{% endif %}
</article>
```

Comment: Hola, @Firiel. Si el tema se trata de HTML y CSS debes compartir el código y compilado para poder evaluarlo. Es decir, el fragmento que estás compartiendo.

Comment: Tienes etiquetas abiertas, confírmalas. Además para poder ayudarte mejor, crea una copia del problema, dado que no podemos cargar los datos que tu tienes. Pero puedes simularlos.